# HTML textarea is unclickable (and can not type inside)

Tags: jquery, html, css, textarea

I'm working on a project in a stand-alone PC so I can not post the code from it, but I have managed to minimize the problem.

I am trying to add a  field but whenever it is clicked, it immediately "loses" the click, making me unable to type in it. The only time I can type and insert input is if I keep the mouse clicked which is very weird for me.

I've been a full-stack programmer for several years and never encountered something so weird.

Please know that this project is only using jQuery and no other framework (Django server-side but that's irrelevant I guess.)

I have gone through quite a lot of similar problems across the internet and stackoverflow but the closest problems were solved by not closing the  tag or not closing  tag above it..

Alright so since I can't post the entire code, I did manage to narrow it down to a VERY weird case.

**HTML:**

```
<body style="width: 1250px; height: 872.8px">
    <div id="taskAnnotationCenterPanel">
        <div id="player">
        .
        .
        .
```

**CSS:**

```
#taskAnnotationCenterPanel {
    width: 83%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}

#player {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Now for the weird part - If I add:
`<textarea rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>`

Inside the `#player` div, its not clickable as I described in the start.
If I put it above it then it works perfectly as expected.
But then if I return the `<textarea>` back in the `#player` div, it works! Very weird and confusing... (All these changes I do through Chrome's F12 devtools to edit the html so I know its not a rendering issue.)

**EDIT:**
Alright so I managed to notice why it gets broken, somewhere else in the code (its from a git's opensource project called cvat) they override the click event of the `#player` div.

How could I remove (using jquery) all existing events of the `<textarea>` which is inside the `#player` div without removing the div's event?

Thanks in advance for ideas for solutions! :)

Comment: make a snippet so we can see what you are talking about

Comment: Yes, we need a reproducible example. I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zp6fb2ch/2/) based on your description, but it doesn't behave as you say.

Comment: Alright so I managed to notice why it gets broken, somewhere else in the code (its from a git's opensource project called cvat) they override the click event of the ```#player``` div.

How could I remove all existing events of the ```<textarea>``` which is inside the ```#player``` div without removing the div's event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to one of cvat's contributers I have found the solution:

`$('#idOfYouTextArea').on('click', e => e.stopPropagation())`

Answer (score 0):

> How could I remove all existing events of the  which is
>   inside the #player div without removing the div's event?

You could try:

```
$('#player textarea').off(<event>);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It didn't solve it.. I've tried:
```$('#player textarea').off("click");```
and ```$('#player textarea').off("mouseup");```